# RxImagePicker not calling completion if orientation changes when taking image

Tags: android, rx-java, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, rx-android

I'm using RxImagePicker to take photos in my portrait-only-forced app:

```
RxImagePicker.with(getActivity()).requestImage(Sources.CAMERA).subscribe(new Action1<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Uri uri) {
            RxImageConverters.uriToBitmap(getActivity(), uri).subscribe(new Action1<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void call(final Bitmap bitmap) {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //i take over here if we ever get here...
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

If I take a picture without rotating the device, it works (although the image is rotated but that's another issue). However, if I take a picture in landscape orientation, `uriToBitmap` is never called. It's not my activity or fragment being restarted, as everything's state is preserved inside my app.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aside from `runonUithread` instead of `observeon(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` , it doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong. RxImagePicker is not able to survive the host activity being destroyed and recreated (which happens on rotation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be something not-so-extraordinary.

I've simply forgot to update to the latest version and was using a few months old version of the library, which had the fix for the problem that I'm facing.

I've updated to the latest version and the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

Acording to sources, `RxImagePicker` uses `PublishSubject` to communicate uri notifications to the client. Picker starts hidden activity, and that activity issues `onCompleted()` in it's `onDestroy()` callback. That callback is called on activity recreation in response to orientation change. Because `Subject` is `Observable`, it obeys to `Observable` [contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html), which states there should be no further notifications after `onCompleted()`, hence `onNext()` notifications following `onCompleted()` are ignored. There is another issue: `onCompleted()` is called twice when image is successfully picked. Seems like there is no workaround, possible solutions:

- Fork library and fix aforementioned issues on your own
- File issue on github so author can address them
- Roll out your own solution ( best IMO)